# Post installing comodo issues

Tags: 12.04, compiling, antivirus

I have installed comodo antivirus for my Ubuntu 12.04, even if I'm a newbie I managed to enter finalize the installation, you know when you have to type `sudo /opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh`, went through the long and boring licence agreement but then I got this message in the end:

```
Build the RedirFS kernel modules for real-time protection...
```

Then

```
linux kernel source or linux kernel headers for your current kernel version 3.8.0-35-generic can not be found.
```

Please install the kernel source or kernel headers for 3.8.0-35-generic, then run this script again.

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=/tmp/driver/redirfs modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.8.0-35-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=/tmp/driver/redirfs modules_install
make: *** /lib/modules/3.8.0-35-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [install] Error 2
FATAL: Module redirfs not found.

RedirFS kernel modules installation failed.

The cmdagent is not running!
$Starting cmdagent: start-stop-daemon: unable to start /opt/COMODO/cmdagent (No such file or directory)
The cmdagent failed to start!
The cmgdaemon is not running!
$Starting cmgdaemon: start-stop-daemon: unable to start /opt/COMODO/cmgdaemon (No such file or directory)
The cmgdaemon failed to start!
```

COMODO Antivirus is successfully configured, you can start it from Menu or Desktop.

So I cannot run the program.

- What can I do?
- What does this all mean and what can I do?

I'm new to this so please make this simple.

Answer (score 1):

But there is soution:

1) You can get this driver "redirfs,avflt,dazuko -- kernel 3.18 or lower" needed from here:

http://www.bondoffamily-net.com/~kinta-chan/techknow/DownLoad/DownLoad.html

2) Go to folder where you downloaded the driver:

`sudo mv driver.tar /opt/COMODO/driver.tar`

3) Then change directory

`cd /opt/COMODO`

4) Install it 
`sudo ./post_setup.sh`
(**Please be carefull** at end of licence you NEED to accept with `Y` and then you can add email address, and choose Language `8`)

5) Restart cmdavd
`/etc/init.d/cmdavd restart`

6) Reboot if must

7) RIGHT CLICK on System Tray icon and click

1. Antivirus Security Level
2. On Access

DONE!!!

Comment: I have kernel 3.13 and it didn't work: purged

Answer (score 0):

Update the kernel and install its headers:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Reboot, then run that script again:

```
sudo /opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and it didn't work...:( If it helps, here is the warning I get when I try to launch comodo: Details: Failed to execute child process "/opt/COMODO/cav" (No such file or directory)

Comment: Ok, I tried to post the results here but it's long and I want to keep it's original format so it wouldn't be hell to read but I don't know how...I'll check it out lol

Comment: I got this: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3564548 Feb 25  2013 /opt/COMODO/cav

Comment: `sudo chmod +w /opt/COMODO/cav` then try again

Comment: It's not working...gives me the same errors. Should I uninstall and reinstall it? You made me update the kernel and all, perhaps just reinstalling the antivirus would work?

Comment: I'm going to try tomorrow and if that doesn't work, I'll uninstall it and find something else lol. Thank you very much for your time and efforts, it is much apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have searched through various posts trying everything that has been said nothing worked. I am a complete newbie to Linux and know nothing but in all the searching for an answer to the problems with Comodo I was ready to give up. In the end I started to think logically and experimenting and bingo I have a green shield.

I searched the TMP file and there was the `driver.tar`. So the answer was to try and move it to /`opt/COMODO`.

In terminal I typed :

`mv /tmp/driver.tar /opt/COMODO`
(Not sure that is right but you see what I mean)

I then ran the `.sh` thing and that was it green shield.
I may be speaking complete rubbish but I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

i run ubuntu 13.10 64bit and this worked for me.
check the 4 steps that kinta-japan suggests:

http://forums.comodo.com/comodo-antivirus-for-linux-cavl/onaccess-scanner-not-working-t86061.0.html

hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, here it is, from Kinta-Japan (http://forums.comodo.com/comodo-antivirus-for-linux-cavl/onaccess-scanner-not-working-t86061.0.html)

Please try this. But, it can't be guaranteed. 
I tested kernel 3.5.0, 3.6.11, 3.7.10 and 3.8.8 on Ubuntu 12.10(x64).
Please tell me result.

(1)
execute CAVL installer.

(2)
download driver.tar from http://www.bondoffamily-net.com/~kinta-chan/techknow/Linux/RedirFS/DownLoad.html

(3)
replace /opt/COMODO/driver.tar

(4)
execute post_setup.sh

Comment: My shield is green now, but the on-access scanner doesnt react to a downloaded EICAR.COM file.

Comment: click '[edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/410847/edit)'. Add important info to your answer then delete your previous commemt.